# Logging good/proven practices - EntLib

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, enterprise-library

I'm currently working on logging for our enterprise application. We (team) agreed on using Enterprise library. And i would need to do some document on this topic, but I'm quite newbie and it's quite hard. I would need if you can make some points what to point out. And what are the best practices. Only what I have found so far is only concrete articles how to do it in code, that isn't what I want, I need some talking about what log, how to log what and so.
It is MVC application written in .Net

Answer (score 2):

I have a general theory about instrumentation. It starts with a "thought experiment". Imagine there is no instrumentation at all in the application, and it gets deployed into Production. What exactly will happen to make us wish that we had instrumented the application?

My answer is that, in general, there will be a set of things that the application knows about that we wish it would tell us. That's the set of things we should instrument.

1. It may be that we would like to have known how often a particular event is taking place (number of times a user gets logged off because the session has expired, for instance).
2. It may be that we would like to have known about any unhandled exceptions (almost free to get this with ASP.NET Health Monitoring, but still).
3. It may be that we wish we had known five pieces of information from the call site of some code that just threw an exception.

The first case suggests we add a performance counter. The second suggests we turn on Health Monitoring. The third suggests we log some additional information at the time of an exception (and then use `throw;` to let the exception propagate).

To my mind, none of these cases suggest it's a good idea to spend time logging every function entry and exit and all the parameters, nor that we should catch every exception and log it before rethrowing it (or ignoring it).

Those things amount to having the program give us "too much information".

Comment: The bottom line is that thinking is still required. Overlogging is an issue, logging for the sake of logging is dumb. I do like the thought experiemnt John proposes - I'd encourage more people to do it when designing their logging strategy.

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're making. I was contrasting the typical strategy of "log everything" with "log only those things you'll miss if they aren't there".

Answer (score 1):

Consider your audience. Logging pops up in these scenarios

for error logging. The audience is the maintenance developer, who really wants to know the true error and the relevant section of code.

for debug/trace. Similar to error logging, but it writes even when nothing has gone wrong. In advance of a bug, it's hard to say what trace will be the most valuable, so you log a lot in areas that you suspect are buggy or in areas where after the fact, you would want to know what methods ran. EntLib is optimized for this sort of logging. EntLib isn't really the best for the other logging goals I'm listing here.

for performance tuning, in which case you really want logging to temporary or just catch the incidents of low performance.

for security, where you are trying to detect incidents of "bad behavior" The audience could be the HR department or law enforcement.

for business driven things. In this case the audience is the client.

Answer (score 0):

The following are some of the best practise about logging in the production system :

- Only log the things that are useful or above a certain logging level .Don't set the logging level too low ,it will cause many things to log.  If you log too much , your application performance will be affected as logging involves file I/O.
- Also log the Thread Name and the class name , it is helpful to debug if the codes are executed by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should think about your requirements (if no business requirements then technical requirements) and try to address them.

In terms of the amount to log, I would lean toward more instrumentation rather than less (provided the levels can be turned up and down).  You will be thankful when you hit that weird production issue that doesn't make any sense.

Here are some considerations:

- Ability to enable different logging levels
- Ability to enable logging for different assemblies/classes
- Ability to enable logging for different functional areas
- Ability to log Method Entries/Exits/timings
- Ability to change logging levels at runtime without a code change
- Where do the logs reside?  Central repository or various distributed logs?
- What is the logging format (e.g. XML)?  Standardized information or ad-hoc?
- Do you need unique EventIDs?
- Will logging trigger alerts/notifications (e.g. Tivoli)? If so, what are the requirements?
- Is it necessary to be able to report/query on the logs

Also, consider using policy injection/AOP for cross cutting logging concerns.

I would recommend not using Priority unless you have a good reason to do so (Category and Severity should probably be flexible enough).

Comment: Are you really going to test all of those options? In particular, are you going to test that your application still works correctly and performs well, with all combinations of the listed options? If you're not going to test them, then don't implement them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, those are considerations and you probably wouldn't implement all of them -- it would depend on requirements. I will just say that I've been involved in projects where most of those items were used/needed.

Answer (score 0):

While thinking about your logging strategy, it's critical to consider how your log entries will be later consumed or processed. Way too often the valuable contextual information is lost as the events get flattened at the time of logging; thus making the logs less useful for troubleshooting.

Semantic Logging allows you to preserve the semantic value of discrete payloads. It also puts the effort in the right place and makes your application code cleaner. I discuss this further in this [post](http://aka.ms/semantic-logging).